# What is the best practice flutter equivalent to react-navigation's createBottomTabNavigator()?

Tags: react-native, flutter, react-navigation

I want to create tab navigation with a custom animated tab bar in Flutter which keeps state of current tab (scroll postion, forms etc) when tabs are switched. This could be done easily in react-native with react-navigation's createBottomTabNavigator(). Because I'm new to Flutter, I don't know the best approach to this.

I can't use TabBar/TabView from material widgets because custom animations in TabBar don't seem possible. So far the only solution I've found is to use IndexedStack widget to store the pages and switch them with a separate tab bar.

Is this the right/best approach? How will it work with hardware back on Android? I would be grateful if someone with more experience could advise on this.

Comment: there is another paging widget, but no one still created a complete solution to all navigation problems like react-navigation and a complete solution means a clean and easy to use one as well